# how to create a new column based on where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display additional columns based on my where conditions. My where conditions based on type. But when I use the following case when condition, I seem to retrieve one row with the hard-coded value and one null row for every match. The non-match have 1 null row. I cant seem to figure out what I have wrong in my case when condition

```
select t1.id,   
  case when   
  t2.value like 'App%'  
  then 'Fruit'  
  end as 'Fruit'  
  case when 
  t2.value like 'Car%'  
  then 'Veggie'  
  end as 'Veggies'  
  case when 
  t3.value = 'Skittles' 
  then 'Candy'  
  end as 'Candy' 
where t1.id = t2.id  
and t1.id=t3.id
```

T1:

```
ID   
1  
2  
3  
4   
5    
6    
7  
8  
9
```

T2:

```
ID(fk)   value  
1        Apple  
1        Orange  
2        Carrot  
3        Berry  
3        Melon
```

T3:

```
ID (fk) value  
4        Mars
5        Twix
6        Skittles
7        Milkyway
```

Desired Output:

```
ID         Fruits     Veggies       Candy    
1          Fruit  
2                      Veggie  
3                            
4                                      
5                                      
6                                    Candy  
7                                       
8                       
9
```

Current incorrect Output:

```
ID         Fruits     Veggies       Candy    
1          Fruit    
1  
2                      Veggie    
2  
3                            
4                                       
5                                     
6                                    Candy   
6  
7     
8                       
9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  t1.id,   
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t2.value like 'App%' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'Fruit'  
  END as 'Fruit',
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t2.value like 'Car%' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'Veggie'  
  END as 'Veggies',
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t2.value like 'Skittles' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'Candy'  
  END as 'Candy'  

where t1.id = t2.id  
  and t1.id = t3.id  

GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: I am not sure I can do a group by as I have multiple other values my query is returning, is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: No, but you can do a `JOIN` after that. `GROUP BY` Include more info and I will see what else can do